# I have all the pieces to the puzzle

Tags: prepositions

Is it grammatically correct to say:

"I have all the pieces to the colorful puzzle."

vs

"I have all the pieces of the colorful puzzle."

Comment: Yeah, either one's OK. _To_ tends to indicate that the puzzle is completely disassembled, and the separate parts all must move together (_to_ somewhere),  but _for_ simply means they are somehow associated with the puzzle by its makers (_for_ the purpose of the puzzle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preposition *to* usually carries a sense of movement; *of* usually refers to ownership or being part of a whole. Both are used in "piece __ the puzzle," but "of" [is much more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=piece+of+the+puzzle%2Cpiece+to+the+puzzle&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpiece%20of%20the%20puzzle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpiece%20of%20the%20puzzle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPiece%20of%20the%20Puzzle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpiece%20to%20the%20puzzle%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpiece%20to%20the%20puzzle%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPiece%20to%20the%20Puzzle%3B%2Cc0).

Interestingly, examining the examples for "piece to the puzzle", or "pieces to the puzzle", these usages with *to* tend to be figurative and refer to a missing or out of place piece that has to be searched for.

e.g., in the [NCI Grading Guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=pDKJhAHGPVsC&pg=PA6&dq=%22pieces+to+the+puzzle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCnZXLw-jbAhUCj1QKHUcWD_oQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22pieces%20to%20the%20puzzle%22&f=false)

> For the newcomer, the process of grading coins can be likened to a jigsaw puzzle. No one book holds all the pieces to the puzzle.